# consuming select list from different class mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I am trying to make my code more readable.
This is an MVC project i am using an hard-coded

```
 ViewBag.Origin = new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Born", Value = "Born"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Donated", Value = "Donated"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Bought", Value = "Bought"}
                        };
```

lot of time in app so i decided to move it into a repository class.

```
public class Repository
{

    public List<SelectListItem> GetOriginList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> originItems = new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Text = "Born", Value = "Born"},
                        new SelectListItem { Text = "Donated", Value = "Donated"},
                        new SelectListItem { Text = "Bought", Value = "Bought"}
                    };

        return originItems;
    }
```

Then tried to access it.

```
public class CowController : Controller
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();

    ActionResult Create() {
     ViewBag.origin = repository.GetOriginList();
    return View();

    }
}
```

My View

@Html.DropDownList("Origin", "Select Origin")

But it view me run time error.

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'Origin' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

Works fine when hard coded on action only.
Am i forgetting any type conversion??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked When I replaced using System.Web.WebPages.Html; 
with using System.Web.Mvc.

I do not know the technical difference.. but if you have same problem you can try my solution...
It would be great if someone could comment with an technical difference...

Another takeaway when i included both reference.

```
Error   1   'SelectListItem' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem' and 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'
```

Comment: Only difference I can see is the WebPages.Html.SelectListItem one has an extra constructor which allows you to pass in a SelectListItem to copy. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.selectlistitem(v=vs.111).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Theres an error there, the case from **origin**. ViewBag uses `dynamic` types, then this will not throw any error in compilation time, but in runtime if something is wrong.

```
ViewBag.origin = repository.GetOriginList();
```

But you calling the DropDownList

```
@Html.DropDownList("Origin", "Select Origin")
```

Its case sensitive, you should change

```
ViewBag.origin to  ViewBag.Origin
```

or call it:

```
@Html.DropDownList("origin ", "Select Origin")
```

EDIT:

Change the Repository function too:

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetOriginList()
```

Comment: ViewBag.Origin = repository.GetOriginList();
Same Error..
Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'Origin' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: Strange!!! Anyway, I tested your code, and works well here! Take a look at the edit!

Comment: Same error
I tried..
List<SelectList> newlist = repository.GetOriginList();
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Do you think i have missed some reference in Repository class??

Comment: Worked When I replaced using System.Web.WebPages.Html; withu using System.Web.Mvc;.... Thanks....

Comment: This is a different error, now you trying to assign a List to a IEnumerable. Do this GetOriginList().ToList()